# Selecting raster class with highest count and attributing it to field polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a 5m satellite image that I classified in ENVI. I brought this classified map into ArcGIS 10x as a .dat image and extracted the raster class for every pixel centre (5m) as a point shapefile. Now I want to intersect the point shapefile with a polygon shapefile: e.g. I have a 160 ac quarter section polygon and have 100's of 5 m pixels within it. My goal is to attribute the field polygon with the dominant raster class.
I am thinking this is a matter of clipping the points within the field polygon, counting the number of raster classes, and selectiing the raster class with the highest count and attributing it to the field polygon.

I am wondering if there is anyway to automate this in ArcGIS?

Comment: If you have Spatial Analyst and the polygons do not overlap, you might want to rethink your approach: keep the image in raster format, convert the polygons to raster, and apply a [zonal majority](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ZonalMajority) to it.

Comment: Thank you. I used your approach and converted my polygon shapefiles into raster. I also converted my classified map into integer classes (crops: canola > 1, barley > 2, wheat > 3). Both my rasters are 8 bit and integer. I used: input raster (polygon to raster output) and zone field "value", input value raster (classified image) "majority" statistics.I get an error and the tool doesn't produce any results! See link: http://postimage.org/image/f5pni88hr/

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/19532-ascii-to-raster-error-10067.  But you have effectively changed your question now, so please edit it accordingly (or remove it).

Comment: Ok, I got the tool to run. But it doesn't produce the results I was looking for.

Comment: Please modify your question to explain what you have done, what you are getting, what results you are looking for, and where the discrepancy is.